# Prompt module in NodeJS repeating the input

Tags: node.js, module, terminal, prompt

I'm making an application using NodeJS and its a CLI application; to get the input from the user, I'm using the "prompt" module. I can use it, but while typing in the prompt's prompt, each character is getting repeated, however the output is fine! The code is below. Please Help.

```
prompt.start();

    prompt.get({
      properties: {
        name: {
          description: "What is your name?".magenta
        }
      }
    }, function (err, result) {
      console.log("You said your name is: ".cyan + result.name.cyan);
    });
```

IMAGE:
[image: added]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before using the "prompt" module, I used the ReadLine interface; sadly I had the same problem. However, the fix was simple:

> Remove the `rli.close();` and then run it.
>
> Then re-add the `rli.close();` and it works!

Thanks mscdex for the input, though :)

Answer (score 2):

FWIW if you just need simple prompting, you can use the built-in [`readline`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/readline.html) module's [`question()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/readline.html#readline_rl_question_query_callback) method (which does not exhibit the double output issue). Example:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rli = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rli.question('What is your name? ', function(answer) {
  console.log('You said your name is: ' + answer);
  rli.close();
});
```

Comment: Tried! Same problem; check the image https://www.dropbox.com/s/dc57u5zcrizktng/Screenshot%202014-11-05%2000.17.13.png?dl=0

Comment: Did you try that code snippet as-is? If the code snippet works then I'd say there's something to blame in the `webpush` script.