# Node readline interface repeating each character multiplicatively

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have created a node readline interface with

```
this.io = readline.createInterface({ 
      input: process.stdin, 
      output: process.stdout,
      completer:(line:string) => { //adapted from Node docs
        const hits = commands.filter((c) => c.startsWith(line.toUpperCase()));
        return [hits.length ? hits : commands, line];
      }
    });
```

When typing the first time into the console, it appears normally, like `> go north`. However, after I take this input, use it in the rest of my code, and prompt the user again with the readline, it appears like `> ggoo nnoorrtthh`, and if I prompt a third time it appears like `> gggooo nnnooorrrttthhh`. I have tried using `terminal:false` when creating the interface but it does not change anything. Is there anything that is making my readline repeat characters that I type multiplicatively?

Edit: I should also add that I'm getting the right output when I parse the user's input into my code (it always returns just "go north"), however it essentially enters the users input twice, and then later three times, and so on.

The code that handles input :

```
let arg = line.substr(firstSpace+1);
        let shouldProceed = this.handler(cmd, arg); //call handler function!
        if(shouldProceed){
          this.io.prompt();
        } else {
          this.io.close();
        }  
      } 
      else {
        console.log('Invalid command. Commands are:', commands.join(', '));
        this.io.prompt();
      }
```

shouldProceed is always going to be true. If the user types "quit", the io will close.

Comment: Try by replacing the last line with `return hits.length ? hits : commands`, the original version seems to be appending each character every time.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change it, I'm thinking that I'm somehow opening the readline more and more each time I call it but I don't know how that would happen

Comment: I think you are missing these two lines `this.io.close();` and `process.stdin.destroy();` in your completer ( I may be wrong here). Source: https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/readline.html

Comment: I close my readline when the user types "quit", and that is the only time it is being closed. Otherwise, when they type another command, my code processes it and then reprompts the user with this.io.prompt() in a recursive pattern. Should I be closing the readline in any other places?

Comment: In this case, you should post the other code along with the question. It will help the community in understanding your problem better. And it won't hurt to try what you are suggesting :)

Comment: If I close the readline prematurely it will not reprompt the user for input and it will terminate the IO, I'm thinking it's more of I'm recursively calling the prompt and somehow that is interpreting my input as two inputs at once

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prompt module in NodeJS repeating the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741503/prompt-module-in-nodejs-repeating-the-input)

Answer (score 5):

I also had this issue. Just fixed it now. It happens if you have more than one **readline.createInterface** in your application. Or atleast you have to make sure that you delete other created interface before using one.

Number of characters repeated is based on how many interface you've created

Comment: Was very helpful. Thanks @dj-hemath. You can resolve this issue by using it as Singleton.
[Code on Gist](https://gist.github.com/ebenjs/8ff23f13e0b12116c269e5ee0a107f8a).